# Centering <a> element with an image inside a div

Tags: html, css, centering

How do I force my `<a>` element with an image appear in center of my `div`? And should I try to center an `a` element first, so it work out?

```
<div class="col-md-6 logo">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">
<img src="#">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

try `style="text-align:center"` :

```
<div class="col-md-6 logo" style="text-align:center">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">
<img src="#">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: He might also need to style the img `display:inline-block;`

Comment: img are by default inline

Answer (score 0):

put your img a class like

In css

```
img.example { margin : auto; }
```

Comment: `margin : auto;`  won't have an effect, as long as the `img` has the default value `inline` for `display`. Beside that `margin : auto;` requires a `block` display and the `width` has to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, navbar-brand has
    float:right 
by default. so i shanged it to 
    :none; 
and 
    text align: center;